# Object to Array (an array of arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, arrayofarrays

I am trying to convert an object literal into an array of arrays by using a function.

Using the two sample objects I have, the end result I'm looking for would be:

`[ ["ugh","grr"] , ["foo", "bar"] , ["blah" , 138] ]` from `obj1`

`[ "shambala","walawala"] , ["foofighter","Barstool"] , ["blahblah",1382342453] ]` from `obj2`

```
var obj1 = {
  ugh: "grr",
  foo: "Bar",
  blah: 138
}; 

var obj2 = {
  shambala: "walawala",
  foofighter: "Barstool",
  blahblah: 1382342453
};

var piece1 = Object.keys(obj1);

var piece2 = Object.values(obj1);

var result = [ ];

for (var i = 0; i < piece1.length; i++) {
 result.push([piece1[i] , piece2[i]])
 }

console.log(result)
```

From what I have above, I have been able to achieve:

`[ ["ugh","grr"] , ["foo", "bar"] , ["blah" , 138] ]` from `obj1`

But I am stumped about how to achieve the same output via a function.

This seems like a simple thing.

```
function objToArray(objectLiteral) {

var piece1 = Object.keys(objectLiteral);

var piece2 = Object.values(objectLiteral);

var result = [ ];

for (var i = 0; i < piece1.length; i++) {
 return result.push([piece1[i] , piece2[i]])
  }
 } 

console.log(objToArray(obj1))
```

This is what the best I can do but I keep on getting 1 and I don't know why.
Other attempts I just end up with undefined.

Comment: [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array after you've pushed an element to it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is you're using the `return` earlier than needed, see this working code:

```js
var obj1 = {
  ugh: "grr",
  foo: "Bar",
  blah: 138
};

var obj2 = {
  shambala: "walawala",
  foofighter: "Barstool",
  blahblah: 1382342453
};

function objToArray(objectLiteral) {
  var piece1 = Object.keys(objectLiteral);
  var piece2 = Object.values(objectLiteral);
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < piece1.length; i++) {
    result.push([piece1[i], piece2[i]])
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(objToArray(obj1));
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone that commented/read/contributed anything.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Tha'er, you hit the nail on the head.  It was the misplaced return.

Answer (score 2):

If it's supported in your environment, you could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
var obj1 = {
  ugh: "grr",
  foo: "Bar",
  blah: 138
};

var pairs = Object.entries(obj1);
```

Alternatively, you could write an `entries` function like this:

```
function entries(object) {
  const pairs = [];
  for(let key in object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      pairs.push([key, object[key]]);
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd implement it.

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(prop) {
        return [prop, obj[prop]];
    });
}

// ES2015
function objectToArray (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(prop => [prop, obj[prop]]);
}
```

[View demo](https://jsbin.com/gecudegabo/edit?js,console)